# Undefined index in php/mysql script

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi I wrote code for load 5 elements from database on 1 page but it's show me a notice Notice: Undefined index: recordstart

Here is my code

```
   <?php
    include 'php_script/init.php';
    $pagesize = 5;

                $recordstart = (int) $_GET['recordstart'];
                $recordstart = (isset($_GET['recordstart'])) ? $recordstart : 0;


                $sql01 = "SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY year DESC LIMIT $recordstart, $pagesize";
                $records=mysql_query($sql01);

                $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM movies");
                $totalrows = mysql_fetch_row($result);

                while ($movies=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
                    echo '<div class="movie_box"><p><div class="news_img"><div class="cover"><img src="'.$movies['cover'].'" width = "183px" height = "271px"/></div><br><button class="trailer_button" type="button">Trailer</button></div><strong><p class="h3"><div class="content">'.$movies['name'].'</p></strong>'.$movies['plot'].'<br><br><strong>Žanr</strong>:'.$movies['genre'].'<br><strong>IMDB ocjena</strong>:'.$movies['IMDBrating'].'<br><strong>Director</strong>:'.$movies['director'].'<br><strong>Glumci</strong>:'.$movies['Starring'].'<br><strong>Ocjena korisnika</strong>:</div><br><div class="trailer">'.$movies['trailer'].'</div><div class="dark"></div></p></div>';
                }

                if ($recordstart > 0){
                    $prev = $recordstart - $pagesize;
                    $url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?recordstart=$prev';
                    printf('<a id="prev" href="%s"><<</a>',$url);
                }

                if ($totalrows > ($recordstart + $pagesize)){
                    $next = $recordstart + $pagesize;
                    $url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?recordstart=$next';
                    printf('<a id="next" href="%s">>></a>',$url);
                }
?>
```

I can't solve my problem with another answers!!!

Comment: there is no solution for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need this line.

```
$recordstart = (int) $_GET['recordstart'];
```

You're checking and setting it already here

```
$recordstart = (int)(isset($_GET['recordstart'])) ? $_GET['recordstart'] : 0;
```

Comment: but it's show me same notice again

Comment: You removed the line I stated wasn't needed and it still said `undefined index`?

Comment: Oh, one sec missed one thing updating...

Comment: oh sorry it says variable not index

Comment: Okay, should be all set now, see update. Sorry missed you were using variable, not `$_GET` on second line .

Comment: You also may want to do a `is_numeric` check on the `recordstart` GET because as is if it isn't a number it will be empty.

Comment: now it's good thanks, but now show me another error Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: See this thread for that error, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole This thread is resolved though now, I think.

Comment: I already checked that...and when I am on main page it's alright but when I press second page it shows me

Comment: Check the values on the second page. Check what the query gives you back from the DB when you execute it there (if anything). Debug a bit, go step by step until you find the issue; or POST the simplest case to reproduce and post that with values. This should be a separate thread though as this is a separate issue.